# RequiredFieldValidator runat"server" error

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I am very new to asp and I am trying to validate some field in a grid view.

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameValidMod" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Value is Required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

I am getting an error like: "tag server is not well formed" on the line of the RequiredFieldValidator. I do not understand why. Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` element, the `Text` attribute is missing a space from the previous one (`ControlToValidate`). That should be what is causing the error.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I did not note it. Thanks.